# Show that $\left(\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & a \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}, a\in\mathbb {R}\right\},\times\right)$ is not a group.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}, a\in\mathbb {R}\right\}$ .Show that under usual matrix multiplication $G$ is not a group, though $G$ has a left identity and right inverse for every element with respect to that left identity.

My solution goes like this:

> If $A\in G$, then if $A=\begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & a \\
> 0 & 0 \\
> \end{bmatrix}$, then we know that $\det(A)=0$. This is true for all elements in $G$. Thus , $A^{-1}$ does not exist. So, no inverse exists for any $A\in G$. Hence, inverse property is not satisfied.  Thus, $G$ is not a group.

Is the proof valid? Is it correct? If not, then where is the problem occurring? Also $I$ is the $2×2 $ identity matrix such that $A.I=I.A=A$, but $I\notin G$, so identity property is not satisfied,  right?

Comment: You are correct, a matrix with determinant zero cannot have a multiplicative inverse. This is a linear algebra fact. Catherine is right, even if you delete the zero matrix from the set of 2 by 2 matrices, the resulting structure is still not a group.

Comment: If an identity exists, it would not be the $2\times2$ identity matrix, which (as you noticed!) is not even an element of $G$. Is there any element $X \in G$ such that $AX = A$ for all $A \in G$? Can you conclude from this that $G$ has no identity element?

Comment: @catherine Well, $I$ is not even in $G$ , and we know that $A.I=I.A=A$, and this $I$ is unique ...so from there cant we conclude that $G$ is not a group ?

Comment: We should limit ourselves to working with elements of $G$. If $G$ is a group, then it should have an identity (which is not $I_2$) among its elements. Can such an element be found? What happens if you multiply two arbitrary elements of $G$, say $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & b \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: @catherine But my logic is that $A.I=I.A=A$  is a fundamental property of matices and now we know that $I\notin G$ , then we already know that no other matrix $B\neq I $ cant replace the function of $I$ as identity from the property of matrices and now since $I\notin G $ hence, $G$ has no identity element.Doesn't this provide a much sufficient reason to conclude the fact that $G$ is not a group?Although$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & b \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & b \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$,but the left identity cant be unique...

Comment: Consider instead the set of matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. Now $I$ is not in this set, but it is nevertheless a group with identity $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. (It is isomorphic to the multiplicative group $\mathbb{R}^*$).

Comment: Going back to the question: in a group, the unique identity element serves as both the left and the right identity. Given the calculation you have done, can a right identity exist at all?

Comment: @Franklin: For matrices, $det(A) \neq 0$ if and only if there exists an inverse matrix of $A$, i.e. a matrix $B$ such that $AB = BA = I$. In the example by catherine, the identity element is not the identity matrix $I$, but $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @catherine $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & b \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & b \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ , here if we place $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & c \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ in place of $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ , the result is still the same i.e it gives $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & b \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$...so the left identity is not unique , right? Also, an observation if $A,B\in G$, then $A.B=B$ is always true ,right? Do we have to prove this?...

Comment: @catherine is this fact sufficent that no unique left identity exists and hence it isn't a group ?...Also we can never ever get a right idenity because if $A,B\in G$ then $A.B=B$, right?...

Comment: Yes, $AB = B$ for any $A,B \in G$ - you've already proved this with your calculation! Indeed, the left identity is not unique and there is no right identity.

Comment: @cathetine so this fact(i.e left identity is not unique and there is no right idenity) is sufficient to prove $G$ is not a group , right?...

Answer (score 1):

You are (understandably!) confused about the exact nature of the neutral element of a group or monoid and possible subgroups or submonoids.

Since we're working in the set of *all* real $2\times2$ matrices, which is not a group (not every matrix has an inverse), but a monoid, it is useful to talk about monoids first. As a reminder, a monoid is essentially a group where one of the axioms has been relaxed: the existence of an inverse for every element is not required, though a neutral element is still required to exist. For instance, the reals with multiplication are not a group but a monoid, since $0$ has no inverse.

In a monoid $M$ (and thus also in a group, since groups are just stricter monoids), the neutral element $e$ has the defining property that for *all* elements $a\in M$ we have $ea=ae=a$. This neutral element is unique in the sense that there is only one element with the *exact same* property: acting neutrally on *all* elements of $M$. But what is not unique is a "partially neutral element". An element $\epsilon\in M$ which acts neutrally on *some*, but not *all* elements of $M$ may exist without interfering with the uniqueness of the neutral element. For instance, in $(\mathbb R,\times)$, every element is partially neutral, since every element acts neutrally on $0$: $r0=0r=0$ for all $r\in\mathbb R$. The same happens in matrix monoids, but in a more interesting manner. For instance, the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Acts neutrally on any matrix of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix},$$

but not on any other matrix. This makes it a partially neutral element in the set of all $2\times2$-matrices, but not *the* neutral element, which is still unique.

However, now let's move to just a subset of this matrix monoid: the set of all real matrices of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Now in *this new, different* set, our partially neutral element acts neutrally on all elements. No wonder, since I specifically chose all the elements on which it does act neutrally to construct this set. So in this subset we have a new neutral element. It is not sufficient to show that the original neutral element is not included, since a new neutral element may arise, that formerly only acted neutrally on a subset, but now acts neutrally on the whole remaining set.

By the way, for this reason the latter monoid is not called a submonoid of the former, even though it's a subset of the monoid with the same multiplication. Submonoids are required to have the same neutral element as their parent, so a subset that is a monoid is not a submonoid, in contrast to groups.

Now to your actual question: Find out what the right identity is. Hint: It's not the identity matrix! Use that to find out what the left inverse of each element is. Hint: it's not the usual matrix inverse! Then show that it is not a right inverse. In a group, the unique left inverse is automatically a right inverse.

Comment: Well, we can easily show that $\forall A,B\in G$, we have $A.B=B$, so we have no unique left identity as $\forall A\in G$, if $B\in G$, then $A.B=B$. Also, any right idenity cant exist as if $A\in G$ is a right idenity then $\forall B\in G $, we have $B.A=A\neq B $, so no unique left idenity exists and neither any right identity exists . Thus, no  idenity element exists in $G$, and hence $G$ is not a group. Is this proof correct? If not, where is it going wrong?...

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Thank you! I do get it now...Thanks a lot!...